# Unexpected mail exchangers from nslookup

Tags: mx-record, windows-10, nslookup

I'm working on Windows 10 and I want, for example, to get the MX server of the site achab.it. Asking for `nslookup -type=mx achab.it`, I am expecting to obtain:

```
Server:  anyres1.fastwebnet.it
Address:  62.101.93.101

Non-authoritative answer:
achab.it        MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mail.achab.it
achab.it        MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = mail2.achab.it
```

or something like that. Instead I get:

```
Server:  anyres1.fastwebnet.it
Address:  62.101.93.101

Non-authoritative answer:
achab.it.fastwebnet.it  MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mx2.fastwebnet.it
achab.it.fastwebnet.it  MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mx4.fastwebnet.it
achab.it.fastwebnet.it  MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mx1.fastwebnet.it
achab.it.fastwebnet.it  MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mx3.fastwebnet.it
```

where `fastwebnet.it` is my service provider.

Same problem with setting other servers, e.g. `nslookup -type=mx achab.it 8.8.8.8`.

I cannot see what's wrong. Isn't it the right way to get automatically the domain mail.achab.it starting from achab.it?

**UPDATE**: The output is the same even if I ask for `nslookup -type=mx outlook.com` or `nslookup -type=mx fakesite.nodomain`

Comment: Can you post the DNS config of achab.it?

Comment: @mzhaase How can I do it?

Comment: Your service provider should expose DNS options to you somewhere.

Comment: I don't know if I said that badly but achab.it is not a site of mine. The problem is client-side (see the update).

Comment: Complain ***loudly*** to `fastwebnet.it` about them breaking DNS. In the meantime, you could try `nslookup -tmx achab.it.` (notice the `.` at the end) to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: `nslookup -tmx achab.it.` returns `95.110.166.82` (i.e. `www.achab.it`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often forgotten that a DNS name end with a "."

To ease user life, many software accept the name without the ending dot and add it automatically.

Without it, the entered name is supposed to be relative.

Relative to what? To whatever DNS suffix is configured on the host.

Windows (as other OS do) actually manage several DNS suffixes. If you type "ipconfig /all" you'll find a `Primary DNS suffix` (that may be empty) and one or several `Connection-specific DNS suffix`
There's also additional DNS search suffixes that can be configured.

You can control this in the advanced properties of TCP/IP in your network card properties:
[image: DNS properties]

When performing lookup for a relative name  (that does not end with a dot) windows will try to resolve it with those suffixes.

It seems your modem receive the DNS suffix fastwebnet.it from your provider and this settings is transferred to your machine through DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's something in the way either your DNS client or your provider's DNS server is setup.

If the issue is replicated with the DNS server at 8.8.8.8, then I think your local resolver is appending a search domain it shouldn't be.

Looking at your output, the 'right' response is being returned: `achab.it.fastwebnet.it` is not the same as `achab.it`, and the first form's answer could well be correct (i.e. any MX request within fastwebnet.it will return this response).

In more technical terms, you are getting an answer for a relative domain name + your search domain.

So the first thing I would check is what the output of `nslookup -type=mx achab.it.` is (notice the ending `.`). That would make the request a fully qualified one, and should get your sanity back.

I am not sure how one goes about addressing this on Windows, I am afraid - on linux, this is something that would be fixed by adding `options ndots:1` to resolv.conf (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html).